# Symfony 1.4 Permissions and Credentials AND OR not working

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Need to know if I'm missing something... I'm using sfGuardPlugin and trying to get a complex credential to work... and it's not even that complex.  I just can't get either AND or OR to work.

"user_a" is set up to have permission "A" in both permissions and group "A" which also has permission "A" assigned to it.

I also have a Permission "B" and a group "B" set up in the same fashion as above... however, I did not assign user_a to these permissions.  To be clear: user_a only has A permissions.

Now in security I have the following (where the user needs to either have credential A or B):

```
dashboard:
  credentials: [[A, B]]
```

Now when I try to have user_a access the dashboard, it fails and redirects to the credentials required page.  I tried the same thing with an AND statement and set up user_a with both, using:

```
dashboard:
  credentials: [A, B]
```

...again, it failed.

Now, when I remove the brackets, and just use one credential, it all works perfectly.  It's just when I use them in combination, in any form, that I run into problems.

Furthermore, I have checked if the user has a single credential, using:

```
echo $user->hasCredential('A');
```

And it responds as expected: True

But if I assign the user to both A and B and then try either:

```
echo $user->hasCredential(array('A', 'B'), false);
```

or

```
echo $user->hasCredential(array('A', 'B'));
```

It responds with False.

I'm stumped.  What am I missing?  I MUST have at least the [[OR]] working.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a work-around?

EDIT: code snippet in myUser.class:

```
public function hasCredential($permission_name)
    {
    //this overrides the default action (hasCredential) and instead of checking
    //the user's session, it now checks the database directly.  
    if (!$this->isAuthenticated()) {
      return false;
    }
    $gu = $this->getGuardUser();
    $groups = $gu->getGroups();
    $permissions = $gu->getPermissions();

    $permission_names = array();
    foreach($permissions as $permission) {
      $permission_names[] = $permission->getName();
    }
    foreach($groups as $group) {
      $group_permissions = $group->getPermissions();
      foreach($group_permissions as $group_permission) {
        $permission_names = array_merge($permission_names, array($group_permission->getName()));
      }
    }
    $permission_names = array_unique($permission_names);
    return (in_array($permission_name, $permission_names)) ? true : false;
  }
```

EDIT:

The above code snippet is indeed the problem.  I tested it without the code snippet and it works as expected.  So my next question, is how to tweak the snippet to accommodate instances with AND or OR?  Suggestions?

Comment: I guess in your test that when you assign both credentials you get True both `$user->hasCredential('A')` and `$user->hasCredential('B')`. Where is security.yml? I'm reading `dashboard` action... are you using sfAdminDashPlugin?

Comment: security.yml is in my config folder for each module.  I am not using sfAdminDashPlugin.  'dashboard' in my example above is just a named module of mine.

Comment: ...could really still use some help on this problem.  Does anyone have any idea or suggestion as to where to begin troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: I was thinking about... I'm using settings like [[A,B]] without problem but just as user permissions and works fine, but I don't use group. Maybe something in permission settings is wrong... the user is in group B and permission B is a group permission (in sf_guard_group_permission) or an user permission (sf_guard_user_permission), and so which permission is assigned?

Comment: I'll tinker around with that and see if that helps.  Currently, user_a is assigned to a group_permission.  But I think I recall changing these settings around to individual permissions only and then group only, without any affect.  But I'll try it again and see if I can narrow it down.  Thanks for not forgetting me... I was about to write a whole new permission check in the action if I couldn't get it to work... and that's a whole lot of work I'd rather not do if I can avoid it.

Comment: You're welcome, let me know how it will go.

Comment: bad news: no change.  user_a is still denied access if assigned to a group or individual permission.  :(  Any other recommendations?

Comment: I "think" I may know what is causing the issue.  I am using a snippet in myUser.class to check the database (instead of the loaded credentials - so if permissions change during a session the database is consulted instead of the loaded permissions).  I've updated my question to include the snippet.  I'm wondering if this is the cause?

Comment: could you write the exact settings (group, permissions, conditions...) so I can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  user_a has group permission Z.  Group permission Z carries a permission of A.  indexSuccess.php security.yml: index: is_secure: true  credentials: [[A, B]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to close this question, because I have found the problem and I will open a new question as a result of the issue I'm having with the code snippet (which becomes a new question).